# JQuery generate drop-down list dynamic default selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am building a DataTable and everything renders perfectly fine.

one of the columns, I need to render a select/drop-down list and set default selected value.

I managed to render

```
render: function (data) {  
  //e.g. data.selectedvalue = 1 or 2 or 3
        
 var select = $("<select class='target' id='empstatus'><option value ='1'>Open</option><option value ='2'>Close</option><option value ='3'>N/A</option></select>");

 //tried to set value - but it is not setting default selection, always shows the first selection after it renders
 select.val(data.selectedvalue).attr('selected', 'selected');


 return select.prop("outerHTML");
}
```

This list renders, my question how can I set dynamic selected value?

Comment: `select.val(data.selectedvalue)` sets the selected option. You don't need `.attr()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the attribute of the appropriaet option, not the dropdown, so that it will be included in the `outerHTML`.

```
render: function (data) {  
  //e.g. data.selectedvalue = 1 or 2 or 3
        
  var select = $("<select class='target' id='empstatus'><option value ='1'>Open</option><option value ='2'>Close</option><option value ='3'>N/A</option></select>");
  select.find(`option[value=${data.selectedvalue}]`).attr('selected', 'selected');

 return select.prop("outerHTML");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense! It works, just had to change the format to find('option[value=' + data.selectedvalue+']') any ideas why your format didn't work? I would get Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: option[value=${data.selectedvalue}]

Comment: Are you sure you copied the backtick correctly? That's an ES6 [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: you right, I thought I had to use this format quote ' changed to yours ` and all works! Didnt know ` is used in jquery. Thanks!

Comment: It's just plain JavaScript, nothing to do with jQuery.